# React empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have some problems with my react app.
I want to foreach some data, but it always retrieve empty Object.

This is my app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setSearchField, requestRobots } from '../../appRedux/actions';


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    searchField: state.searchRobots.searchField,
    games: state.requestRobots,
    isPending: state.requestRobots.isPending
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onSearchChange: (event) => dispatch(setSearchField(event.target.value)),
    onRequestRobots: () => dispatch(requestRobots())
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onRequestRobots();
  }

  render() {
    const { games, searchField, onSearchChange, isPending } = this.props;

    console.log("here it is" + games);



    return (
      <div className='tc'>
        <h1 className='f1'>RoboFriends</h1>
        <SearchBox searchChange={onSearchChange}/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Where I have `console.log("here it is" + games);` it always retrieve empty data, but when I  do console log in actions.js that looks like:

```
import {
    CHANGE_SEARCHFIELD,
    REQUEST_ROBOTS_PENDING,
    REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS,
    REQUEST_ROBOTS_FAILED,
  } from "../../constants/ActionTypes";
  import axios from 'util/Api'


  export const setSearchField = (text) => ({ type: CHANGE_SEARCHFIELD, payload: text })


  export const requestRobots = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ROBOTS_PENDING });
      axios.post('/games',
      ).then(({ data }) => {
        console.log("Games data: ", data);
        if (data.result) {
          dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
        } else {
          dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ROBOTS_FAILED, payload: data.error });
        }
      }).catch(function (error) {
        dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ROBOTS_FAILED, payload: error.message });
        console.log("Error****:", error.message);
      });
    }
  };
```

See that I have `console.log("Games data: ", data);` and I'm successflly getting informations that I need?
This is how backend response looks like:

```
{
    "result": true,
    "games": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "panelgameid": 71,
            "img": "https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/67/50/EkSo4r.jpg",
            "name": "Counter-Strike 1.6",
            "active": 1,
            "minslots": 12,
            "maxslots": 32,
            "slotincreament": 2,
            "order": 1,
            "prices": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "gameid": 1,
                    "location": "Serbia",
                    "price": 0.6
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "gameid": 1,
                    "location": "Germany",
                    "price": 0.4
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

Redux part

```
import {CHANGE_SEARCHFIELD, REQUEST_ROBOTS_PENDING, REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS, REQUEST_ROBOTS_FAILED} from '../../constants/ActionTypes'

const initialStateSearch = {
    searchField: ''
  }

  export const searchRobots = (state=initialStateSearch, action={}) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case CHANGE_SEARCHFIELD:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {searchField: action.payload})
      default:
        return state
    }
  }

  const initialStateRobots = {
    robots: [],
    isPending: true
  }

  export const requestRobots = (state=initialStateRobots, action={}) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case REQUEST_ROBOTS_PENDING:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {isPending: true})
      case REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {robots: action.payload, isPending: false})
      case REQUEST_ROBOTS_FAILED:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {error: action.payload})
      default:
        return state
    }
  }
```

Comment: When you say "always retrieve empty Object", is it an actual empty object (i.e. `{}`) or is it just an empty array (i.e. `[]`)? It will likely be empty on the very first render (depending on reducer/initial state value). Can you share your redux reducer that processes that `REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS` payload?

Comment: Well when on  console.log("here it is" + games); console looks like 'here it is[object Object]', Yes I will update the post

Comment: Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Your `requestRobots` state slice *is* an object with shape `{ robots: any[], isPending: boolean }`. It also isn't an empty object (don't believe me, try `console.log("here it is" + JSON.stringify(games))`). Presumably you are trying to iterate over the `robots` array, yes?

Answer (score 0):

In your `mapStateToProps` you are assigning `state.requestRobots` to `games` , but your state contains `{ robots, isPending }`. So try changing mapStateToProps to

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    searchField: state.searchRobots.searchField,
    games: state.requestRobots.robots,
    isPending: state.requestRobots.isPending
  }
}
```